# Как взять value конкретного button, которые формируются с помощью PHP и имеют одинаковые классы?

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Есть несколько тегов button, которые формирует PHP вида: `<button class="view_more" value="1">View More</button>`. Как с помощью JQuery получить value того элемента, на который я кликнул? Мой код всегда выбирает value первого элемента:

```
$(".view_more").click(function() {
    var note_id = $(".view_more").val();
    $.get('test.php', {tool:note_id}, function(data) {
        $(".content").text(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: в ф-ю передаётся параметром элемент, поймавший событие:

    $( ".view_more").click( function( e){
        var v = $( e.target).val();

Comment: @Sergiks, передается. Только не параметром, а `this`. И, насколько понимаю, там могут быть несовпадения `e.target` с желаемым элементом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Атрибуты такого типа как `value` (это может быть и `title` и `data-id`) у тэга `button` получаются через метод [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), ваш код будет выглядеть так:

```
$(".view_more").click(function() {
  var note_id = $(this).attr("value");
  $.get('test.php', {tool:note_id}, function(data) {
    $(".content").text(data);
  });
});
```

А `$(this)` внутри функции `click()` определяет по какому именно элементу вы нажали.

Answer (score 0):

В твоём коде переменная note_id указывает на первый элемент из списка элементов с классом .view_more, а событие ловит нажатия на любой из них.
Ниже исправленная версия

```
<button class="view_more" value="1">View More</button>
<button class="view_more" value="2">View More 2</button>
<button class="view_more" value="3">View More 3</button>

<script>
  $(".view_more").click(function() {
    var note_id = $(this).val();

    $.get('test.php',
      {
        tool: note_id
      },
      function(data) {
        $(".content").text(data);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вместо выборки по классу:

> ```
> var note_id = $(".view_more").val();
> ```

Используйте выборку с помощью this. С помощью this можно обращаться к текущему элементу и собственно ко всем его атрибутам:

> var note_id = $(this).val();